# converting Int Dates to Date variable lubridate

Tags: r, date, lubridate

I have a data frame with a column of dates as integers e.x. 192606 192607 etc..
My date values are just years and months
I would like to change this integer form to a dateform so I could plot them in a time series plot (ggplot)

I tried using lubridate but I get an error massage.

```
sss[,1]<-ymd(sss[,1])
```

EDIT:

Data can be found here: https://mba.tuck.dartmouth.edu/pages/faculty/ken.french/data_library.html

I am working with 25 Portfolios sorted on size and book-to-market

EDIT 2:

Here ist the output of my data frame.
I appreciate your fast help! Thanks

str(sss)
 num [1:1122, 1:5] 192607 192608 192609 192610 192611 ...
 - attr(*, "dimnames")=List of 2
  ..$ : NULL
  ..$ : chr [1:5] "Time" "Intercept" "Mkt" "smb" ...

Comment: Do those numbers come from an Excel worksheet? MATLAB? What is their origin?

Comment: The numbers come from an csv file yes, and are imported to RStdio and converted to a data frame

Comment: What is equivalent date of `192606` ?

Comment: It is the year of 1926 and month of July

Answer (score 0):

The `ymd` requires that it is a character vector with the order of dates following year, month, day in any format as long as the date is in that order. Your column is of type integer and hence breaks these rules. So use either `as.Date()` from base, or `as_date()` from `lubridate`

```r
as.Date(192606)
"2497-05-03"
lubridate::as_date(192606)
"2497-05-03"
```

Therefore, for your data:

```r
sss[,1] <- as_date(sss[,1])
```

If data is not numeric:

```r
sss[,1] <- as_date(as.numeric(sss[,1]))
```

Since the format is YearMonth we can use:

```r
library(zoo)
sss[,1] <-  as.yearmon(as.character(sss[,1, drop = T]), "%Y%m")

head(sss[,1])
# A tibble: 6 x 1
  Date     
  <yearmon>
1 Jul 1926 
2 Aug 1926 
3 Sep 1926 
4 Oct 1926 
5 Nov 1926 
6 Dec 1926
```

If `sss` is a matrix, wrap `as.character()` around the `as.yearmon` call. This is because, with a matrix, all the data must be of the same time. When types are mixed, all data is coerced into factors. This is why you get the values you do. So convert the column to character before the data is coerced to a factor.

```r
sss[,1] <- as.character(as.yearmon(as.character(test[,1]), "%Y%m"))
```

Although this works, you should probably stick with data frames when dealing with data like this.

Comment: My coloumn has around 1200 dates, no way I would write each one specifically

Comment: The sss[,1] <- as_date(sss[,1]) solution sets my values to NA

Comment: Are you sure the column is numerics? It might be of type character or factor. Please edit your answer with the output of  ````str(sss)````

Comment: Thanks for your help! I tried as_Date and it changes my output to different time -->192606 becomes 2497-05-04. The basic as.Date() says I need an origin

Comment: I didn't realise the format of the date until I saw the Fama and French data. The final code I've posted works now.

Comment: Thanks!  It did change the output but to values such as 1926.500 1926.583 1926.667 for dates of 192607 192608 192609. Is there a way to format the output to "1926-06"

Comment: @TheRipper7000  I downloaded the data from the Fama and French website, ````sss[,1] <-  as.yearmon(as.character(sss[,1, drop = T]), "%Y%m")```` works for me.

Comment: @Ronak Shah, your answer produces a single NA for me with the data I downloaded. Setting ````drop=TRUE```` gives a vector of dates in the format of "Mar 1928"

Comment: I am not sure `drop = TRUE` is worth a separate answer. If I were you, I would have commented on other person's answer to correct it. Anyway...

Comment: @Mr.Rlover if I use it on the original file I receive the Month and Year as output. But if I try it on my matrix I receive the output 1926.500 1926.583

Comment: That explains it then, a matrix requires all data to be of the same type, so the data is coerced to factor if there is different data types in the column, hence why your values are strange.

Answer (score 0):

See if this helps.
The problem seems to be that those numbers should not be seen as numbers but as character strings coding dates in the format `"YYYYMM"`. So to coerce to R class `"Date"`, first paste a day `01` then coerce with `as.Date`.

```
sss <- matrix(
  c(192607, 192608, 192609, 192610, 192611, 192612, 192701, 192702, 
    192703, 192704, 192705, 192706, 192707, 192708, 192709, 192710, 
    192711, 192712, 192801, 192802, 192803, 192804, 192805, 192806, 
    192807), 
  ncol = 1)

d <- as.Date(paste0(sss[, 1], "01"), format = "%Y%m%d")
head(d)
#[1] "1926-07-01" "1926-08-01" "1926-09-01" "1926-10-01" "1926-11-01"
#[6] "1926-12-01"
```

Comment: @TheRipper7000 See the new code. I believe this is it.

Comment: How would it be possible to chang this output to a matrix so I could combine it with another matrix?

Comment: @TheRipper7000 If you want to `cbind(other_mat, d)` this output is OK. If the data set is not a matrix but a `data.frame`, then `df$newcol <- d` will do it. Can you give an example of what you mean?